# Employee benefits not signed up by hr

Tags: law, life-insurance, benefits, employment-law, georgia

I enrolled in life insurance for myself and my husband on hire and open enrollment. He now has passed away. The life insurance company said hr never enrolled him. So no policy. Do I have any recourse?

---

Yes I have copy of benefit enrollment confirmation The benefit administration company hired by my employer did not complete my election for his policy - they did for our mutual dental benefits, my life insurance policy and health insurance policy

The insurance company says no policy issued prior to his death so they can’t issue on deceased person. Benefit administrator cannot go back and correct that mistake

Who pays?

Comment: How long was it between the time your signed up and the date of his death? Was the insurance free or was there a monthly price to be deducted from your paycheck? Did you successfully signup for other benefits?

Comment: This is more of a legal question than a financial one, but do you have any evidence that they said they were signing him up? You will likely wind up in court if you want to recover anything.

Comment: Please see https://money.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts for help on getting your two accounts merged